# How does Shazam tell people his name?

Tags: dc, shazam

Shazam turns into a superhero and back by saying his name. So how does he introduce himself?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean Captain Marvel?  Whose name is not Shazam?

Comment: He spells it out, of course. :P

Comment: Though, to be serious, I think it's just a plot-hole related to the fact that he _didn't_ used to be called Shazam! and DC wanted to keep that iconic cry in DCnU while ditching the 'Captain Marvel' name. Or perhaps intent is necessary for the transformation.

Comment: The same way Beetlejuice does - charades!

Comment: So wait, is the Wizard no longer named Shazam?  Man, I really do not like the new 52 at all!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the wizard is still named Shazam!, but I don't think the character (Captain Marvel) has ever been called Shazam!,  unless recent canon has changed that.

Comment: @Zibbobz - He's now called Shazam! due to a rights dispute with Marvel Comics.

Comment: @Zibbobz - http://www.geeksofdoom.com/2012/01/30/captain-marvel-officially-becomes-shazam-in-dc-comics

Comment: I came here looking for Shaq and was disappointed.

Comment: @Koveras Shaq is **Kazaam** and really, why would you actively look for something so vile as that anyway?!?

Comment: @Shisa But Captain Marvel Jr. had that problem from the start, because his magic word was "Captain Marvel".

Comment: Alan  Moore played on this difficulty in his “Marvelman” (later retitled “Miracleman”) comics, which were a pastiche of Captain Marvel.  Analogous to Captain Marvel Junior, Kid Marvelman transforms by saying “Marvelman!”.  In a battle, when he has defeated the heroes, all seems lost, but he makes the mistake of saying his _own_ name during his final gloating: “Now I'm going to finish him off! Me!  His adoring junior protoge!  Me, **KID MARVELM**… …an."  «HHRRRRAAAAKKK».   Oops.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not saying the word "Shazam" that results in his transformation, it's saying the word "**Shazam!**" (complete with exclamation mark in most cases) and **with the intention of transforming**.

As you see from the panel below from the [Curse of Shazam](http://www.dccomics.com/tags/the-curse-of-shazam), he's perfectly capable of introducing himself without transforming:

[image]

In short, he introduces himself by saying "Hello, I'm Shazam"

Comment: @user14111 - Wikipedia suggests it was automatic and happened at least once by accident

Comment: I don't think the intention necessarily has to be transformation, seeing how often he uses the lightning as a weapon. But yes, you seem to be right about the fact that intent matters.

Comment: Gonna have to read that comic. The reason why I asked was I was reading Injustice (like an alternate timeline thing, if you didn't know) and Wonder Woman got Black Adam to say his magic word with the Lasso Of Truth and he turned back into himself. I assumed that meant Shazam would have the same problem, although from what I'm hearing it sounds like it's whatever's convenient to the writers.

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Pre-crisis it appears to have been different.  For instance in DC Comics Presents # 34 where Superman is in Captain Marvels dimension and they temporarily both change by saying Shazam!  the following dialogue appears where Captain Marvel is starting to talk about Supermans X-ray vision: "..How'd you ever learn to control that power, so you didn't become a peeping tom?"  "Same way you learned not to say Shaz-- er, that word-- in the middle of a volcano!"

Comment: I like that explanation!  But now I'm wondering what would happen if he said "Shazam factorial."

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/shazam-reveal-seventh-champion-king-kid/

Answer (score 13):

#### Saying [Shazam!](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/William_Batson_(Prime_Earth)) only matters when William Batson has focused his will and intent behind it. At any other time it's just a word.

In the New52 version of Shazam, we are introduced to the Justice League (Justice League #00, 2012) with the retelling of the origins of the **[Big Red Cheese](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Billy_Batson)**. When Billy Batson appears in the tower of the Rock of Eternity, the last of the wizards awaits him.

[image]

The wizard, running out of time tells Batson to say Shazam. Batson tentatively asks "Shazam?" Nothing happens.

[image]

The wizard admonishes him when nothing happens.

[image]

This time, when Batson says it with intent:

[image]

In previous continuities, it was possible for Batson (or any of his partners) to say their "magic word" by accident and be transformed or at least trigger the lightning. Likely this effect was played for humor in the early decades of the character's existence.

Comment: It was sort of played with humor, mostly it was because his name was Captain Marvel and the only time he said Shazam was to transform

Answer (score 4):

Spoiler warning for *Shazam!* (2019):

> The movie reintroduces the problem Shazam has when introducing himself. During the scene where he explains himself to Darla, he mentions how the wizard made him say "Shazam". As soon as he said it, he transformed, and it was clear from the scene that he didn't mean to transform.

Answer (score 3):

It was a problem that Captain Marvel Jr. had as HE transformed by saying "Captain Marvel". *However*, it appears that, as of *Shazam!* #1 (January 2019), Shazam has the same problem.

> SHAZAM: You're going to have to guess. I've been having a bit of trouble saying my name recently.

[image: Picture from Shazam! (2019) #1. All rights property of DC Comics.]

As you can see from the picture, Billy is saying that he no longer has control of the lightning when he says the Word.

Answer (score 2):

The characters of the name SHAZAM! all represent a powerful champion, even the exclamation point.
 "It took the combined might of Solomon, Hercules, Atlas, Zeus, Achilles, Mercury and ! to stop and contain Mister Mind." Shazam, current run, issue 2 tells us there was another champion, represented by  "!" that is part of Billy's transformation. Therefore, the exclamation point is part of the name, and if only "Shazam" and not "Shazam!" is spoken, the transformation is not triggered.