# What happens when adult Billy Batson says "Shazam"?

Tags: dc, shazam

Billy Batson is a kid who transforms into a superpowered adult when he says "Shazam". But when he grows up, does saying "Shazam" just give him the suit and powers or does it make him look any different?

Comment: Related
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/how-does-shazam-tell-people-his-name

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Kingdom Come* (1996) had an adult version of Billy Batson, who upon saying "Shazam" changed into Shazam/Marvel. I see no particular difference in his Shazam look than in the one he typically changes into when Billy's depicted as a kid.

[image: Adult Billy says Shazam]

[image: transformed adult Billy]

This is very much in line with what "the wizard" said in *Shazam!* #1 (2013): he didn't make Billy older, he transformed him into his full potential. I guess that if you're going to throw punches at demigods (or even gods), "full potential" will always come in the form of a burly 30-something man<sup>1</sup> regardless of the host's original body.

[image: Billy discusses with the wizard]

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For a male host, at least. Mary Marvel, the female version of Shazam, doesn't look so burly.</sub>

Comment: That *Kingdom Come* scene is one of my all-time favorite comic book moments

Comment: It might also help to note that up until that scene in Kingdom Come (rather late in the story), all the other heroes thought he was Shazam (Captain Marvel) full-time, and were surprised to find it was instead a mentally scrambled adult Billy Batson they'd been dealing with.

Comment: And for a non-canon answer to what would happen to Billy Batson if Shazam decided to stay in charge full-time, just have a look at Alan Moore's run of Miracleman... ;)

Comment: so adult Billy looks different than shazam?

Comment: Note as well that his evil counterpart, Black Adam, does revert to an old man or even dust in many incarnations.

Comment: @Antheloth: No, they look identical so you can't tell the difference (barring clothes).

Comment: @Kamalen the implication is that the host still ages when he's in Shazam form. The question was asking the reverse, whether Shazam aged when the host lives their normal life, hence why I didn't include Black Adam in that answer; although you're totally right :)

Comment: If Captain Marvel is now called Shazam, what is Shazam (the wizard) called now?

Comment: @user14111 he's still Shazam, apparently. I guess Billy and him are not seen together enough for that to become confusing. At least that's how he's named [on DC's website](https://www.dccomics.com/characters/wizard-shazam), and I guess there's more on the link at the bottom of the page, but I can't access it right now as I'm not in the US

Answer (score 0):

Even in the Ordway interpretation of Captain Marvel, his superhero form was manifested from Billy's ideal self image, which was that of his own Father. So it can be assumed that Billy would  grow up to be the spitting image of his Father.

Comment: If you havea panel to [edit] in, this would make for a better answer :)